# mysql - Inability to connect using procedure that has been in place for years

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I use a procedure during tax season to connect from a script on my workstation to a production mysql server. The procedure has been in use since 2007. This year I am unable to connect to the mysql server, getting "access denied for user 'xxx'@'localhost'". The command line is as follows:

mysql -u xxx -p -h ourmysqlserver

where "xxx" and "ourmysqlserver" are dummy names used for this question.

When I ping ourmysqlserver, it resolves to the expected IP on our VPN.

I would not expect 'xxx'@'localhost' to be able to connect, as there are no grants for 'xxx'@'localhost' because it is not appropriate. Rather we have always used 'xxx'@'10.8.0.%', where the 10.8.0 network is our VPN. It does not make sense to me have have localhost because that either implies I am coming in from an account on mysqlserver, or I am trying to connect to a local instance of mysql, neither of which I am trying to do.

On a hunch, I entered GRANTS for 'xxx'@'localhost'. You would think that that would then work. But that does not work either.

While this procedure has been in place a long time, over the years our DNS, VPN, mysql server, mysql client, and host server configurations have changed.

I am suspecting that there is something in the configuration of the mysql client that is forcing it to act in an unexpected way. But I would like to resolve this so as to be able to continue using existing procedures.

EDIT: I discovered that by switching the -h parameter to an IP address instead of a DNS name, that the connection can be made. It is still a mystery why the DNS name cannot be used in some place (it still works fine elsewhere) and why 'localhost' appears in the error message.

Comment: May be  more of a http://dba.stackexchange.com question.

Answer (score 0):

My immediate guess would be a dns vs hosts file issue.  I may be that with the hosts file, it is resolving to the loopback adaptor and then when you try to do a reverse dns lookup, it comes back as localhost.

In other words, my guess is that this is what happens:

1. host ourmysqlserver probably resolves locally to 127.0.0.1
2. 127.0.0.1 resolves to localhost via reverse dns
3. the ip address resolves to the correct hostname via reverse dns

The problem is probably in /etc/hosts

Comment: You might be onto something. However, checking /etc/hosts, there is an entry for "ourmysqlserver" which resolves to the IP address on the VPN. According to that entry, it seems that the DNS name should just work, and that I should not have to hard code that same IP address.